# The left-hand side of an 'in' expression must be a private identifier or of type 'any', 'string', 'number', or 'symbol'

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to fix this type error , even that i already define a String type to key parameter.

```
function checkIsExistObjectKeys(object: Object, key: String): Boolean {
  return key in object;
}

console.log(
  checkIsExistObjectKeys(
    {
      name: "john",
      lastName: "Francois",
    },
    "name"
  )
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key parameter should be of [type `string`, not `String`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean).

Comment: my bad :) am new in TS

Comment: Yeah - it's not the most helpful error, not sure what it thinks a "String" is.

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkIsExistObjectKeys(object: Object, key: string): boolean {
  return Object.keys(object).some(x => x === key);
}
```

Comment: yes but i don't want use !!object[key], because a pair key with value undefined will return false , for instance , console.log(
  checkIsExistObjectKeys(
   {name: undefined} ,
    "name"
  )
);// false

Comment: I edited my answer, i think that will do the trick

Comment: thank you , but i want keep using the `in` syntaxe , my error was using String instead of string , ps it's not me who downgrade your answer , thank you again

Comment: Your answer was likely been down-voted because it's just code. When providing code on stackoverflow please add some explanation of how it works to solve the question.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.